# can't assign a class to a table being used for a sql select/update

Tags: php, css, mysqli

I'm running a query that outputs to a table that I use to update my records.  The table is rendering too large for my page because of the side bar I'm using.  I tried assigning it a class and then using **CSS** to size it so it fits where I want it, but I'm getting this error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting ',' or ';'
>   in...

I'm using a similar class elsewhere in my webpage and it works well.  Any help getting it fixed would be greatly appreciated.  Here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang = "en">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
    <title>Tech Order Department.html</title>
    <meta charset = "UTF-8" />

<style>

div {
    text-align: justify;
    }

.section {
     margin-left: auto;
     margin-right: auto;
     width: 70%;
    }
</style>


</head>

<body>

<nav>

    <h1>Yulista</h1>
<br>
    <h2>Explore</h2>
    <ul>
<br>

<form>
<INPUT Type="BUTTON" Value="Home Page" Onclick="window.location.href='http://www.oldgamer60.com/Project/sidebar.php'"> 
</form>

<form>
  <p><b>Project Status<br/></b>
      <select name="select" onChange="window.open(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value,'_self')">
      <option value="">Select one</option>
      <option value="http://www.oldgamer60.com/Project/CurrentProjects.php">Current Projects</option>
      <option value="http://www.oldgamer60.com/Project/ProjectsInFinalReview.php">In Final Review</option>
      <option value="http://www.oldgamer60.com/Project/DeliveredProjects.php">Delivered</option>
      <option value="http://www.oldgamer60.com/Project/CompletedProjects.php">Completed Projects</option>
    </select>
  </p>
</form>

<form>
  <p><b>Updates<br/></b>
      <select name="select" onChange="window.open(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value,'_self')">
      <option value="">Select one</option>
      <option value="http://www.oldgamer60.com/Project/ClientUpdates.php">Client Updates</option>
      <option value="http://www.oldgamer60.com/Project/mynewform.php">Project Updates</option>
      </select>
  </p>
</form>

<form>
  <p><b>New Business<br/></b>
      <select name="select" onChange="window.open(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value,'_self')">
      <option value="">Select one</option>
      <option value="http://www.oldgamer60.com/Project/NewProject.php">New Project</option>
      <option value="http://www.oldgamer60.com/Project/NewClients.php">New Clients</option>
      </select>
  </p>
</form>



<br>
</ul>
    </nav>

<h1>Logistics</h1>

<br>
<h2>Updates</h2>


<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "oldga740_Tonymm";
$password = "JtAjDm#6";
$dbname = "oldga740_SeniorProject";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
     die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

if (isset($_POST['update'])){
$UpdateQuery = "UPDATE Projects SET Project='$_POST[project]', Client='$_POST[client]', LastName='$_POST[lastname]', DateReceived='$_POST[datereceived]', FinalReviewDate='$_POST[finalreviewdate]', DateDelivered='$_POST[datedelivered]', DateAccepted='$_POST[dateaccepted]' WHERE Project='$_POST[hidden]'";
mysqli_query($conn, $UpdateQuery);
};

$sql = "SELECT * FROM Projects";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

echo "<table class="smaller">
<tr>
<th>Project</th>
<th>Client</th>
<th>Last Name</th>
<th>Date Received</th>
<th>Final Review Date</th>
<th>Date Delivered</th>
<th>Date Accepted</th>
</tr>";

while($record = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
if ($result->num_rows > 0){

echo "<form action='mynewform.php' method='post'>";
echo "<tr>"; 
echo "<td>" . "<input type='text' name='project' value='" . $record['Project'] . "' /></td>";
echo "<td>" . "<input type='text' name='client' value='" . $record['Client'] . "'/></td>";
echo "<td>" . "<input type='text' name='lastname' value='" . $record['LastName'] . "' /></td>";
echo "<td>" . "<input type='text' name='datereceived' value='" . $record['DateReceived'] . "' /></td>";
echo "<td>" . "<input type='text' name='finalreviewdate' value='" . $record['FinalReviewDate'] . "' /></td>";
echo "<td>" . "<input type='text' name='datedelivered' value='" . $record['DateDelivered'] . "' /></td>";
echo "<td>" . "<input type='text' name='dateaccepted' value='" . $record['DateAccepted'] . "' /></td>";
echo "<td>" . "<input type='hidden' name='hidden' value='" . $record['Project'] . "' /></td>";
echo "<td>" . "<input type='submit' name='update' value='update' /></td>";
echo "<td>" . "<input type='submit' name='delete' value='delete' /></td>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "</form>";
}
}
echo "</table>";



?>

<?php
    $conn->close();
?>



</body>

</html>
```

my css:

```
table.smaller { width:80%; }
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a small syntax error in your code. Here's the fix:

```
// your code

echo "<table class=\"smaller\">
<tr>
<th>Project</th>
<th>Client</th>
<th>Last Name</th>
<th>Date Received</th>
<th>Final Review Date</th>
<th>Date Delivered</th>
<th>Date Accepted</th>
</tr>";

// your code
```

Comment: `"<table class=\"smaller"\>"` should be like this right, count of quotes only 3 so?

Comment: Not required, there's a closing `</tr>"` at the end.

Comment: This seems correct. Alternatively, you could change it to `echo '<table class="smaller"> .... </table>'` (note single quotes around the output). The issue is OP is using the same type of quote.to denote the start of a string being outputted and an attribute value.

Comment: @DACrosby yes, OP can use either of these methods to resolve syntax error issue.

Comment: I tried that too but it generates another syntax error here echo "<form action='mynewform.php' method='post'>";

Answer (score 0):

Add `';'` after `window.location.href='http://www.oldgamer60.com/Project/sidebar.php'`-

```
<INPUT Type="BUTTON" Value="Home Page" Onclick="window.location.href='http://www.oldgamer60.com/Project/sidebar.php';">
```

Comment: Single statement doesn't need semicolon(`;`) at the end.

Comment: @ Rajdeep Paul - Ohh,so only if appending return true/false etc statements `;` this is necessary?

Comment: Yes, if it has multiple statements, then semicolon(`;`) is used separate each statement.

Comment: Your answer too will result error right?,isn't that need to be- `"<table class=\"smaller"\>"` quotes is missing right?